# How to read all url params using js?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way, how to read url params?

```
www.example.com/detail?id=12
www.example.com/detail/12
```

Return 12...

I do not know what the parameters are. I want to return all.

Comment: Of the current URL or from a string?

Comment: From a string..

Comment: var url = new URL(yourUrlString);
url.searchParams contains many methods which you can use to get all the params or a specific param
You can use polyfills if you want this to be supported in lower versions of IE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href` to get your URL with parameters.

To access the id parameter in your second example (www.example.com/detail/12)

```
var url = window.location.href;
return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

If you don't need it to work in Internet Explorer, you can also implement [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) which allows you to define a URL object and retrieve params directly from it:

#### Examples from [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
var paramsString = "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api";
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

//Iterate the search parameters.
for (let p of searchParams) {
  console.log(p);
}

searchParams.has("topic") === true; // true
searchParams.get("topic") === "api"; // true
searchParams.getAll("topic"); // ["api"]
searchParams.get("foo") === null; // true
searchParams.append("topic", "webdev");
searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api&topic=webdev"
searchParams.set("topic", "More webdev");
searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=More+webdev"
searchParams.delete("topic");
searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams"
```

Comment: `let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);` [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get#examples)
You can use this code to get only the search parameters from the url.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the all the params together as an object as follows

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams('?one=1&two=2');
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlParams.entries());
console.log(params) // {one: '1', two: '2'}
```

Answer (score 3):

1.Using `location.href` get all url.

2.Find `?` char and split domain and parameter.

3.For each split `=` char,you will get all parameter value.

```js
var url = location.href;

if(url.indexOf('?')!=-1)
{
    var ary = url.split('?')[1].split('&');

    for(i=0;i<=ary.length-1;i++)
    {
       //val is parameter
       var val = ary[i].split('=')[1];
       //alret(val);     
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How do you get the Run code snippet and Copy snippet to answer buttons?

Comment: @Urasquirrel You press `ctrl` + `M` on answer's area,You will see Code Snippet  :).
Run code and Copy snippet are auto created by system.

Comment: Thanks mate! appreesh!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/detail?id=12";//www.example.com/detail/12";
var url = new URL(url_string);
var id = url.searchParams.get("id");
alert(id);
```

Or Try this:

```js
function getParam( name, url ) {
    if (!url) url = location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( url );
    return results == null ? null : results[1];
}
alert(getParam('id', 'http://www.example.com/detail?id=12'))
```

Comment: This doesn't work in any version of Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do such a thing. If you are using a framework or any libraries they may provide a more elegant way of doing this, but by hand:

1. regular expressions I might recommend this if everyone is familiar with them this method can be somewhat more cryptic but more performant.
2. treat the strings as arrays. After the ? index, grab indexes deliniated by the "/" and then the &

```js
    log = (...x) => console.log(...x);
    const url_2 = "www.example.com/detail/12";
    const url_1 = "www.example.com/detail?id=12&thing=blue&sky=red";
    
    const splits2 = url_2.split("/");
    log(splits2); // [ "www.example.com", "detail", "12"]
    log(splits2[splits2.length-1]); // 12
    
    const splitbyquestionmark = url_1.split("?");
    log("splitbyquestionmark", splitbyquestionmark); // ["www.example.com/detail", "id=12&thing=blue&sky=red"]
    const parameters = splitbyquestionmark.splice(splitbyquestionmark.length-1, 1); //["id=12&thing=blue&sky=red"]
    const paramsAsString = parameters[0]; // id=12&thing=blue&sky=red
    const finalParams = paramsAsString.split("&");
    log(finalParams) //["id=12", "thing=blue", "sky=red"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Web API and access window.location.

[Window Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Answer (score -1):

You can grab the GET parameters string and parse through it like this, first turning it into an array, and then construction an object from that array that will give you access to the items:

```
const GETstring = window.location.search.subst(1);

let GETarray = GETstring.split("=");
let GETobject = {};

for(i=0;i<GETarray.length;i++){
    if(i%2 === 0)}{
        GETobject[GETarray[i]] = GETobject[i+1];
    }
}

console.log(GETobject.id) // should print 12;
```

**Edit:**

Daniel's answer shows that the URLsearchParams does this for you so I think it's the better way to go. I wasn't aware of that functionality when i wrote my answer.