# get parameters from URL to html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I created a button in html file that move to page with form:

```
<a class="btn goToProfile" href="{{ url_for('new_meeting', dog =  dog[0] ) }}">Click here to schedule a meeting</a>
```

I add the parameter dog to the GET request

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/new_meeting?dog=123
```

When I move to the new page I have a form:

```
<form action="/favorites/add_meeting" method="post">
    <label for="time">Time:</label><br>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="time" name="time">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="place">Place:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="place" name="place"><br>
    <br>
    <label for="place">Dog ID:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="dog" name="dog" value="1" readonly><br><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I extract the parameter from the URL and add this to the value in the input tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read all url params using js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606857/how-to-read-all-url-params-using-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/7390893) about how to get query parameters with JavaScript

When you have parameters let's say inside `dogName` variable. You can change form input field with id `dog` like this:

```
document.getElementById("dog").value = dogName
```