# Get url parameters in html span element on same page via jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Address of my WordPress website page (page address is http://instanano.com/test/) with URL parameters is, http://instanano.com/test/?a=test1&b=test2&c=test3. Now I want to show "a", "b" and "c" values in span elements on the same page by using jQuery or Javascript. Please suggest me some very simple code which can do it.

```js
$("#span1").text(URL(URLSearchParams.(document.location.search)).searchParams.get('a'));
$("#span2").text(URL(URLSearchParams.(document.location.search)).searchParams.get('b'));
$("#span3").text(URL(URLSearchParams.(document.location.search)).searchParams.get('c'));
```

```html
<span id='span1'>
<span id='span2'>
<span id='span3'>
```

Comment: you didn't even try to fix it. first of all, try to google howto work with url params, it's pretty simple

Comment: Sir, I have google it a lot but did not understand, I know jquery basics but not able to understand. please help sir, if you can

Comment: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is the first thing you should read to start writing some code -  here's the first line for you `const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search)` - the rest is not possible to answer, since I'd need to know what to do with those values to be of any help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606857/how-to-read-all-url-params-using-js

Comment: @Inspectiitd If you don’t understand existing documentation, then please show your research and ask about the things you don’t understand; specify what exactly you don’t understand.

Comment: "SyntaxError: missing name after . operator" - you're so close though `$("#span1").html(new URLSearchParams(document.location.search).get('a'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close, a couple of minor issues with it, plus you're needlessly repeating yourself

Here's how to do it neatly

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);

$("#span1").text(searchParams.get('a'));
$("#span2").text(searchParams.get('b'));
$("#span3").text(searchParams.get('c'));
```

Comment: Sir, spaces are working perfectly in textarea but in span/p/a/div, it is only giving 1 space even if there are more than 1 space

Comment: @Inspectiitd that's how html works

Comment: you could use the `white-space:pre` style to fix that; or replace multiple spaces with multiple char code 160 in the text; or use `.html` instead of `.text` and replace your multiple spaces with multiple `&nbsp;`, or ask a new question and get some help that way